# Solana: Check if deposit is finalized?

Tags: transactions

How can we check if a deposit is finalized using solana/web3.js? Must we use `getTransaction` or `confirmTransaction`? In the case of `confirmTransaction` it takes too long for us to get a response whereas `getTransaction` returns suspiciously quick. So I am not sure which one to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your overall goal and need for speed but a transaction status check under many circumstances will probably suffice: getsignaturestatuses

web3:
https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/modules.html#SignatureStatus

jsonrpc:
https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getsignaturestatuses

websockets:
https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#signaturesubscribe

Comment: Do you think this is the same kind of method used by services like solana explorer to check if a transaction is finalized or not? I am looking for a way conclusively say if a transaction is finalized or not.

Comment: solana explorer is open source, so you could also check there for the approach they use:
https://github.com/solana-labs/explorer

Answer (score 3):

`confirmTransaction` should be used right after `sendTransaction`, when you know the transaction is not confirmed yet. It sounds like this is the method you want to use. And yes it does take a while for the transaction to confirm, and to get the response.

`getTransaction` should be used for historic data, when you want to retrieve the data of transactions you know have already succeeded.

Comment: I am wondering what's the method used by services like https://explorer.solana.com/ to show that a transaction is confirmed and finalised! Could it be `confirmTransaction` ?